# How to sort time in sql based on the current time?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This cursor is grabbing all the data from the colum dateday which is above the current date, and it sorts it correctly, the time column is also sorted correctly by I keep getting values which happened before the current time. For example, i want 10:00:00 returned because it is higher then 09:00:00, but i don't want 08:00:00 returned due to it already occuring.

```
    public Cursor GetFirstTime(){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor nextTime = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM time_table where dateday >= date('now') AND time >= time('now') ORDER BY dateday, time ASC LIMIT 1",null);
        return  nextTime;
}
```

Comment: Show some example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think about just storing a long value of the milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (`calendar.getinstance().gettimeinmillis()`). With this, you only need to store one long value in the database and your database query will be more simplified:

```
COLUMN_DATE_TIME >= "specific long value"
```

Comment: I was gonna answer the same thing. Always store on your date/times as Linux epoch (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is just an `long` so all comparison are very simple operations.